# SVN - Migrate to new server

Tags: rhel5, svn

We recently acquired another company that brought with them some crufty old linux servers.  One of them is their SVN server - **which died last night**.

I don't know a lot about Subversion, but I have reading up on it this morning - as you can imagine.  We do have backups, but their just the whole directory tree for the subversion, not individual dumps.  Since the server is now dead, I cannot do any dumps.

How do I migrate that Subversion directory to a new server and get it up and running again?  I'm not seeing a lot of examples.  The new server is a VM running RHEL5.

Thanks,
Jeff

Answer (score 1):

Use svnadmin dump and svnadmin load to create a portable dumpfile on the old server and then load it on the new server.

Comment: The old server dies last night, so no such luck being able to take a dump. I have the directory tree in our backup. Any easy way to 'import' it?

Comment: If you have a backup of the repository itself, then just restore it to the new server, and as long as you are using the same version of subversion as before it should just work as is.

Comment: So just copy the backup of /opt/subversion to the new server at /opt/subversion and then...?  I'm a little foggy on how to setup Apache, et al, and point it to this copy of subversion.

Comment: The redbook has instructions: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.serverconfig.httpd.html

Comment: For future, you should be using `svnadmin dump` to make backup copies, because it is much easier to restore with `svnadmin load` -- as mentioned in this answer.